# How to split surfaces

Tags: modeling, mirror, extrude

I wish to create an edge by extruding a vertex and thereby splitting a surface in Blender 3.2.

Entered edit mode

[image]

Selected a vertex in vertex mode.

[image]

Extruded the vertex with the y constraint.

[image]

Surface does not split as expected.

[image]

I can't find the CG Essentials tutorial on how to do this. I did get it to work once, but I don't seem to be able to repeat it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think what you want is the knife tool.

Comment: Or, subdivide an edge and G + G vertex slide to get it in place, and then connect the two vertices with J to split a face

Comment: Is this the CG Essentials tutorial you were referring to?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gt-E2kPs2hY

Comment: That's exactly it thanks curious_1 and thanks Allen Simpson for your help. That's working now. Although I'm playing with splines instead of loopcuts. So I actually won't need the subdivision modier. But it's good to know thanks.